# Check if there any changes to realm object

Tags: java, android, realm

If the realmObject from a result has a value changed, is there a way to detect it?

```
Account account = mRealmInstance.where(Account.class).equalTo("isLoggedIn", true).findFirst();

account.setName("New Name");

if(account.hasChanged()){ //Is there a realmMethod for this?

}
```

Comment: You can add listeners to the `RealmObject`, but it will be called when the db changes but not only the `RealmObject` changes. A more proper implementation will come later, see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/989

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd assume that this is what you're looking for?

```
RealmChangeListener<Account> listener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Account account) {
        // changes have been made to Account table
    }
}

Account mAccount;

mAccount = mRealmInstance.where(Account.class).equalTo("isLoggedIn", true).findFirst();
if(mAccount != null) {
    mAccount.addChangeListener(listener);
    //assuming I'm in a transaction here
    mAccount.setName("New Name");
}

...

if(mAccount.isValid()) {
    mAccount.removeAllChangeListeners();
}
```

Although I do think the `RealmChangeListener` is activated whenever there's a change to the `Account` table, and not just when this particular object is modified.

(EDIT: since Realm 3.1+ the realm object listeners are also fine-grained so it is modified only when the selected account is modified)

Comment: Not sure about the activation. It seems that the onChange method is called ONLY when you modify the selected Account in the Account table.

Comment: @Tobliug since Realm 3.1+ the realm object listeners are also fine-grained so it is modified only when the selected account is modified

Comment: Is there any way to check if the whole table is modified or not?

Comment: Add a RealmChangeListener to `realm.where(MyObject.class).findAll*()`